# How to understand closed, convex sets whose points do not have common support?

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, convex-analysis

Let $K_1$ and $K_2$ be closed, convex subsets of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$. For $x \in \mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}^n$, let $s(x) = \{i \in \{1,...,n\}: x_i>0\}$ be the *support* of $x$. I'm trying to better understand the following property:

> (*) For all $x \in K_1$ and $y \in K_2$, $s(x) \neq s(y)$.

Obviously, if (*) holds, then $K_1 \cap K_2 = \emptyset$. But the converse isn't true: $K_1$ and $K_2$ can be disjoint and have points with common support.

This is open-ended, but I'm simply looking for a convenient necessary and sufficient condition for (*).

Any hints or references are appreciated.

Comment: If $K_i=\{(i,i,...,i)\}$, for $i=1,2$, then $K_i$ are closed convex and if $x\in K_1$ and $y\in K_2$ we have $s(x)=\{1,2,...,n\}=s(y)$. The same is true if $K_1=K_2=\{(1,1,...,1)\}$.

Comment: Are you assuming $x_i \geq 0$ always holds? That is, no negative coordinates?

Comment: @MPW Yes, edited. Thanks.

Comment: The condition $(*)$ is odd. If $K_1$ contains *any* point in the open "quadrant", then $K_2$ must lie entirely within the bounding coordinate planes, right?

Comment: @MPW Yes, that seems right to me.

Comment: Subspaces take you outside of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq}^n$, better use cones. Now, what you need to take is not the cone generated by $K_1$ and the one generated by $K_2$. Even if they only intersect at the origin, the supports can still be non-disjoint. Example: $K_i=\{(t,i\cdot t):\ t\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}\}$, for $i=1,2$. You need to take the smallest coordinate cone. A coordinate cone containing $K_1$ and the one for $K_2$. A coordinate cone would be a cone generated by a subset of the standard basis $e_1,...,e_n$.

Comment: @LB_O Yes, what you're saying seems like it aligns with my geometric intuition, but I don't know how to formalize it. Maybe you can provide more details?

Comment: It is probably worth considering what a minimal/maximal set of points with a given support $s$ actually is. In particular, the simple cases $\{x:s(x)=\{1\}\}, \{x:s(x)=\{1,2\}\}$ etc

Comment: I already defined what is a coordinate cone. There are finitely many of them and at least one $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}^n$ contains any subset of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}^n$. Therefore, for every subset of $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}^n$ there is a minimum coordinate cone containing it. The supports of the points in the coordinate cone generated by $e_{k_1},...,e_{k_m}$ is contained in $\{k_1,...,k_m\}$. Therefore, if the minimal coordinate cones containing $K_1$ and $K_2$ only intersect at the origin, then in particular the supports of their points are disjoint.

Comment: @LB_O Okay, I will think about it. Thanks. About your example---I think it must contain a typo. That or I don't understand the notation.

Comment: @MPW Yes, I did consider such "maximal support sets". So we can say that there is no maximal support set that meets both $K_1$ and $K_2$. I guess I was just hoping for something more informative because that doesn't improve on (*) much to my mind.

Comment: @LB_O Okay, so we can say that (*) holds iff $K_1$ and $K_2$ are contained within disjoint _open_ coordinate cones, where by _open coordinate cone_ I mean a coordinate cone in your sense with $0$ removed. Is that right?

Comment: It tells you that not only must $K_2$ not meet $K_1$, but also it must not meet the maximal support set of $K_1$. Moreover, the maximal support set of $K_2$ also has this property (it must not meet the maximal support set of $K_1$).

Comment: @MPW Perhaps we should clarify our terms. When I said "maximal support set" I meant a set of the form $\{x: s(x) = \{i_1,...,i_j\}\}$, as in your previous comment. What do you mean by "maximal support set _of K_i_"?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm thinking. Your maximal set is the same as $s^{-1}(\{i_1,i_2,\ldots,i_j\})$. So I'm thinking of a union of such sets, so I think $s^{-1}(s(K_1))$. Here, $s(K)=\{s(x):x\in K\}$.

Comment: These sets are like vertices, edges, faces, etc in a complex. For $n=1$, you have $0$ and $R_+$. For $n=2$, you have $0\times 0$, $R_+\times 0$, $0\times R_+$, and $R_+\times R_+$. For $n=3$, you have a similar set of permutations of $0\times 0\times 0$, $R_+\times 0\times 0$, $R_+\times R_+\times 0$, and $R_+\times R_+\times R_+$ (8 altogether).

Answer (score 1):

Referring to my comments above, I think that $(*)$ holds if and only if $K_1$ and $K_2$ are contained in disjoint unions of these maximal classes.

Each such maximal class (in $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^n$) is the Cartesian product of $n$ factors, each of which is either $\{0\}$ or $\mathbb R_+$. There are precisely $2^n$ such classes. Note that the classes are pairwise disjoint and they exhaust $\mathbb R_{\geq 0}^n$.

Comment: Yes, I think this is right. I'm leaving the question open for the time being, as I'm still hoping for more illuminating characterizations of (*). Thanks!

Comment: Also, I think it's true that the convexity of $K$ implies the convexity of $s(K)$. Do you agree?

Comment: Note that these classes are just the faces of various dimensions of something like an $n$-cube. So the $K_i$ just don't meet the same face.

Comment: I think you may be right about the convexity. But you should define it carefully because the values of $s$ lie in $\mathbb N^n$, not in $\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think what I mean is: the union of the support sets that meet $K$ is convex if $K$ is.